# How to deliver a custom 404 Error from a perl script?

Tags: html, perl, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have an .htaccess file which calls a perl script if certain conditions are met. The htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml

#check existence
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} (.*)

#redirect for codes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[css|jpg|gif|png]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /cgi-bin/normalized\.pl?code=$1 [R=301]
```

Codes get passed to the normalized.pl file such that if the URL requested was www.domain.com/code1, "code1" would be passed. If the code exists I can refer the user onwards to the correct page.

However, if the code doesn't exist I wish for the user to be directed to my custom 404 page as defined in the htaccess file.

What seems to happen though is that the htaccess file sees the normalized pl as an existing file and I get a 200 response for the perl script. The perl script then returns a 404 header (as shown below) *but it doesn't show my custom 404 page* - just a browser standard one.

```
print header(-status=>'404 Not Found',-type=>'text/html');
```

I suspect it's because the .htaccess file has already been passed by the time the perl script runs.

How can I convince my browser to display the custom 404 page in this case? Would it be advisable/acceptable to force a 301 redirect from the perl script to the 404 page? But would that have any impact on search engines indexing the pages?

Comment: Are you sure?  Some browsers (including both IE and Chrome) will show their built-in error pages instead of what's sent by the server in some cases.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q218155

Comment: If the .htaccess file comes across a missing file in its course of duty it will show the custom 404. It's only after the normalized.pl file is called that the 404 page fails to display, which leads me to believe that it's not being displayed at all once .htaccess has passed me on to the perl script.

Comment: Again, are you sure? Disregard what a browser displays, use a more low-level tool like a bare-bones HTTP client library (e.g. [lwp-request](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lwp-request)) or a packet sniffer (e.g. Wireshark) in order to view the response in an unadulterated fashion.

Comment: I don't really know what it is I'm supposed to be sure of... Fiddler shows me that if I go to www.domain.com/code the response is a 301 from the .htaccess file to www.domain.com/cgi-bin/normalized.pl?code=code which returns a 404 status. This is the expected behaviour. But my custom 404 page does not display at this point. That's the problem.

Comment: Even if other 404 pages on your domain work, if a specific 404 page (such as the one generated by your Perl script) meets certain (unspecified) requirements, browsers may choose to replace it with their own.  Use something other than the browser for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 header sent by your Perl script only tells the browser that the page was not found.  There is no way for it to tell that to the web server, since the web server considers the request to be successful due to the fact that it found your Perl script.

The only way for you to send your custom 404 page at that point would be to have the Perl script `print` the HTML for it after the 404 header.

Comment: "have the Perl script read its contents and print them" -- his custom 404 page is shtml so I'm guessing that won't quite work as he wants.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel True, some adjustments will be necessary if he uses any SSI directives in the page.  I'll edit the answer to make it more general.